# How do you make a div shaped like a quarter of an ellipse in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

So, how do you make a div that's shaped like the bottom-left quarter of an ellipse in CSS3?

CSS3 supports rounded corners, but there is no obvious way to make a div shaped like a quarter of an ellipse.

The height of the div is supposed to be 50px, and the width is supposed to be 25% of the screen.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: do you want to make round of div corners ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start, the shape you're describing might not always be an ellipse. Depending on the screen size, the 25% width might result in a circle.

That said, here's a simple quarter-ellipse with just a few lines of CSS. The important CSS property being the `border-bottom-left-radius: 100%`.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe simply using border-radius like this :

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Here is another fancy way using radial-gradient and the **ellipse** value:

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 25%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at top right, red 68%, transparent 70%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the other answers who use border radius, here's **another alternative using SVG** :). *Fewer lines of code:*

> You can set the width and height according to your criteria. This is just a demonstration to show easier way to achieve ellipses using SVG.

- There's a **predefined ellipse container**, you just need to `adjust the width and height of the svg container` to clip off and make only **1/4th visible**.

**Here's a demonstration of what the coordinates imply:**

[image]

You can also make use of **viewbox** to *extract the particular part of the ellipse* within the svg:

**The prototype of the viewbox attribute is :**

```
viewBox="x y width height"
```

where **x and y** are the `coordinates of our SVG container` as shown in the diagram below **from where we need to start**, taking the width and height to the right and bottom.

**width and height** are **100 and 50** since that's the `quarter of our ellipse` **having diameters 200 and 100**.

> Note- If you don't use viewbox, by default it takes the x and y
>   coordinates as 0,0 (meaning the origin/ top left corner of the
>   container) so, it will show the output same as the first quarter
>   below.

```html
<br>Top left quarter: origin(0,0(top left)) :<br>
<svg height="50" width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;" />
</svg>

<br>Bottom right quarter: origin(100,50(Center)) :<br>
<svg height="50" width="100" viewBox="100 50 100 50">
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;" />
</svg>

<br>Bottom left quarter: origin(0,50(Left edge Center)) :<br>
<svg height="50" width="100" viewBox="0 50 100 50">
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;" />
</svg>


<br>Top right quarter: origin(100,0(Upper edge Center)) :<br>
<svg height="50" width="100" viewBox="100 0 100 50">
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="50" rx="100" ry="50" style="fill:yellow;" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```css
#ellipse {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

#ellipse:before {
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

#ellipse:after {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="ellipse"></div>
```

Comment: you can simply apply only one border-radius instead of all and adding element to hide them :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want corners with unequal rounding you can actually do this.

```css
div {
    background-color: #E0EAF1;
    /* percentages allowed as well */
    border-radius: 50px 0 0 0 / 20px 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
Text
</div>
```